# Create "userName" column that is based off of first and last name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise to generate my users. I have a first_name column and a last_name column. Upon submitting the form I'd like for username to become the first letter of the first_first name, plus the last name.

```
first_name: Michael
last_name: Hopkins
user_name: mhopkins
```

I am very new to rails and am not sure where I put this logic. Can anybody help out?

Comment: The good news is, this piece of software is for a group of about 10 people to use. Luckily, there are no duplicate last names or anything goofy like that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way. Put this in your User (or appropriate) model

```
before_create :prepare_username

def prepare_username
 self.user_name = (self.first_name[0] + self.last_name).to_s.downcase
end
```

Note: please make sure you first check first_name and last_name is not empty

Comment: I apologize for the two dumb questions about to ask. I just started learning rails and it's rather daunting.

1. I understand this is a method. But where does user_name get set to the return of prepareUserName

2. If I put form validations that they can't be empty, that would satisfy your note, correct?

Comment: 1. I'm sorry, I forgot to set to the attribute. I've just updated answer. 2. No. I guess, you can check `before_validation` rather than `before_create`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: I haven't gotten to test yet. I figured I would try `validates` to make sure there was a first and last name. then `after_validation` to set the field.

Comment: yeah, that's better approach i think

Comment: Any chance you could take a look at this @HungryCoder? You seem to be quite knowledgeable in RoR 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242668/wrong-number-of-arguments-2-for-4-using-simple-form-checkboxes