# Wrong number of arguments (2 for 4) using simple_form checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, simple-form

I'm a little confused by the read me for simple_form in regards to a collection of check boxes. Namely, what else am I expected to put on the line besides my options. The readme has `:first, :last` but doesn't really explain what purpose those words server.

Below are two different collections of checkboxes I'd like to have. I should also mention, each checkbox relates to a boolean field in the DB and they are labeled the same as the column names.

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :options, [[false, 'App'], [false, 'DB'], [false, 'WCF']] %>
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :options, [[false, 'Com1'], [false, 'Com2'], [false, 'BofA']] %>
```

I forgot to mention, the error I'm getting when I try to load this page is

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 4)
```

Comment: It still doesn't explain what `:first` and `:last` are used for as arguments. Am I always supposed to put first and last? Is it possible those might change? The readme doesn't seem to say

Comment: I wasn’t saying that that link answered your question. I just posted it for the answerers’ convenience, so they could quickly find the README you’re talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error simply mean that your `<%= f.collection_checkboxes %>` takes 2 arguments but your giving it 4. Remember this for future reference as this mistake can be easily made.

Right from this example below:

```
form_for @user do |f|
  f.collection_check_boxes(
    :options, [[true, 'Yes'] ,[false, 'No']], :first, :last
  ) do |b|
    b.label { b.check_box + b.text }
  end
end
```

The rubydoc.info website states the following:

> It is also possible to give a block that should generate the check box + label. To wrap the check box with the label, for instance as above:

So from my understanding of this the `:first` and `:last` represent the labels as it were. So that you'd have two check boxes. That are either `true` or `false` but then outside that option array you are providing the label those instances of the class. So lets take this example. That is providing the label the instances `:first` and `:last` of the class `User`. Hope this clarifies things. The link is provided below:

[Ruby Doc- SimpleForm collection_check_boxes](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/FormBuilder#collection_check_boxes-instance_method)

Comment: I get that I need to pass more stuff in. In the read me the other two arguments passed are `:first` and `:last` however I have no idea what those represent in regards to me or simple_form

Comment: @mhopkins321 just updated the answer this should clarify things up for you :)

Comment: I don't think `first` and `last` are being called on the class `User`. They're being called on each subarray of the array you passed as the second parameter. `:first` is the parameter `value_method`: "the method to apply on the array collection to get the value". And `:last` is the parameter `label_method`: "the method to apply on the array collection to get the label". So, for instance, `[true, 'Yes'].first` produces `true` as the value, and `[true, 'Yes'].last` produces `'Yes'` as the label.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane I stand incorrect. Your right, so in saying that, and breaking that example down more. `:options` is the method. Then the array `[[true, 'Yes'], [false, 'No']` is the collection and `first` is the value method and `last` is the text_method then.